# SSRS - Spacing between lines in single TextBox

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, format, string-formatting, ssrs-2016

I have a flat-file to be load in SSRS report. Which already contains New Line and required spacing. Like the below image:

[image]

Want to display same layout and newlines(CRLF) into SSRS. Which works fine If I use

*≪Place Holder Property → Markup type = "None - Plain text only"≫*

But I want to increase the spacing between Individual new lines.
So I tried below **expression** with the same other properties:

```
=REPLACE(Fields!Column1.Value, Chr(13), vbCrLf)
```

But It has increased the space almost double than my expectation. I also tried to convert *≪Place Holder Property≫* into *≪ HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles ≫*, but It has removed normal new lines which exist into flat-file.

I tried many existing solutions over StackOverflow but none of them are matching my requirement.

Could anyone please give it a try!

**Edit-1**:
`Textbox.line-height` is providing a facility to change spacing between lines, but not reflecting PDF output, only showing the effect on a web browser. My target output is PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the thing you are asking about isn't possible.

`“<br>”` ,`”<p>”`,`vbcrlf`, font setting in textbox of any report ,the list mark , do not work with SSRS.